# Why does the javascript file sometimes not load with the html for Office Addins?

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

I have a taskpane Office Addin that sometimes does not load the javascript file with the html. The user has to click reload a number of times before it eventually does. I know it's not rendering because I've used JQuery to format the buttons and the text does not show up. The buttons also do not call the javascript functions when clicked. Is there anything I can do to correct this?

If the user clicks reload enough times eventually the js file will load but I would like to prevent them from having to do this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a  tag in the bottom of my HTML file with some javascript. After I moved the javascript in the script tag to the .js file instead of the HTML file the javascript file loaded correctly.